# Error in postgresql

Tags: sql, postgresql

i have the following SQL query, but i can't make it work as intended. Why is it giving me this error?
Code:

```
SELECT people.name, teams.teamname
FROM people, teams
INNER JOIN partof ON partof.person_id = people.person_id
INNER JOIN teams ON teams.team_id = partof.team_id
WHERE partof.roletype = 'Coach';
```

Error:

```
ERROR:  invalid reference to FROM-clause entry for table "people"
LINE 3: INNER JOIN partof ON partof.person_id = people.person_id                                             
HINT:  There is an entry for table "people", but it cannot be referenced 
from this part of the query.
```

Comment: Explicit JOIN chains are evaluated before comma separated items. In a JOIN chain only columns from already specified tables may be used in ON clauses. (From left to right.)

Answer (score 4):

*Never* use commas in the `FROM` clause.  *Always* use proper, explicit `JOIN` syntax.  That is your problem.

Try this:

```
SELECT p.name, t.teamname
FROM people p INNER JOIN
     partof po
     ON po.person_id = p.person_id INNER JOIN
     teams t
     ON t.team_id = po.team_id
WHERE po.roletype = 'Coach';
```

The problem is specifically the comma in the `FROM` clause.  The rest of the `FROM` clause doesn't recognize the tables before the comma.  These are the rules of ANSI SQL with the comma.  That is really not important, though.  Just don't use the comma.